# Wrong easter date in php

Tags: php, date

I try to calculate the easter date in php.

```
echo(date("2012: t.n.Y", easter_date(2012)).'<br>'); // 2012: 30.4.2012
```

This date is correct for the eastern orthodox churches. But I want the normal one!

My next try with the `easter_days` function:

```
function easter($year) {
    $date = new DateTime($year.'-03-21');
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.easter_days($year).'D'));
    echo $year.": ".$date->format('t.m.Y') . "<br>\n";
}

easter(2012); // 2012: 30.4.2012
```

Tested oh PHP 5.2.6 and 5.3.6. I also tried to change the timezone with no success.

Comment: CNR: php -r 'echo date("Y-m-d",easter_date(2012));'
2012-04-08 . php -v
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 13 2011 18:18:37)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. `t` is the number of days in the given month (april = 30). Use `d` for day of the month:

```
echo(date("d.m.Y", easter_date(2012)).'<br>');
// will output: 08.04.2012
```

btw: orthodox easter date is April 15th this year.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the DateTime class, the following will give you a DateTime object set to Easter. Use `easter_date()` instead of fiddling around with `easter_days()`:

```
function easter($year, $format = 'd.m.Y') {
    $easter = new DateTime('@' . easter_date($year));
    // if your timezone is already correct, the following line can be removed
    $easter->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
    return $easter->format($format);
}

echo easter(2012);              // 08.04.2012
echo easter(2012, 'd.m.Y H:i'); // 08.04.2012 00:00
```

---

### Timezone

Setting the timezone is only necessary when the default timezone is wrong. Must be set afterwards as it is ignored in the constructor when a unix timestamp is provided.

If left out, the `DateTime` constructor may produce a wrong date (e.g. *07.04.2012 22:00* for 2012 instead of *08.04.2012 00:00*)

Comment: In my experience using "@"+timestamp to set the timestamp in a datetime constructor seems to not set the object's timezone to the script's current timezone, but to UTC for some reason.